# This rewriting code is changing special characters which is unexpected

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

This code is for purpose of removing empty parameters from URL by .htaccess:

```
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+?&)?[^=]+=(?:&(.*))?$
    RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1%2 [R=302,L]
```

It removes empty URLS but the problem is it's changing special characters in URL which caused many errors. e.g: 
`山西省` changes to: `%252525E5%252525B1%252525B1%252525E8%252525A5%252525BF%252525E7%2525259C%2525258‌​1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `NE` flag in your rule.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+?&)?[^=]+=(?:&(.*))?$
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1%2 [R=302,NE,L]
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_ne

Comment: Thanks man! Do you think the code is perfect now for removing empty elements? cause I worry about unexpected errors in future

Comment: NP, I don't see anything wrong with it, but I can see how you could be concerned. You are probably fine now after adding the NE flag. I can't see what else might come up.